# Как передать каждое из значений списка в другую функцию?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, бот, aiogram, schedule

Имеется тлеграм бот, написанный на библиотеке `aiogram`. Пытаюсь реализовать такой функционал: по команде берутся значения из БД и инициируется таск на выполнение функции с определенным интервалом (с помощью библиотеки `aioschedule`). Код на данный момент выглядит так:

```
@dp.message_handler(commands=['check'])
async def cycle_restart(msg: types.Message):
    cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM table WHERE status = ?', ('correct',))
    rec = cursor.fetchall()
    for row in rec:
        code = row[3] #уникальный идентификатор
        uid = row[1] #ID пользователя
        job = aioschedule.every(5).seconds.do(count, c_id=code, u_id=uid)
        while True:
            await aioschedule.run_pending()
            cursor.execute('SELECT status FROM table WHERE id = ?', (code,))
            rec = cursor.fetchall()
            for row in rec:
                if row[0] == 'stop':
                    aioschedule.cancel_job(job)
                    return
            await asyncio.sleep(1)
```

В итоге, даже если в БД присутствует 1+ подходящих строк, то берется только первая и запускается 1 таск. Никак не могу сообразить, как поправить цикл, чтобы задание назначалось с каждой из переменных, полученных из БД.

Comment: Вы уверены, что  WHERE id =   возвращает больше 1 строки ?

Comment: @ProtectchildrenofDonbas2014 да, конечно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сейчас у вас проблема в том, что запустив задачу для первой записи, вы ждете в цикле пока она не закончится, и как только статус меняется на `stop`, вы делаете выход из функции:

```
   if row[0] == 'stop':
       aioschedule.cancel_job(job)
       return
```

и все остальные записи выбранные первым запросом пропускаются.

Похоже, что вы хотите запустить задачи для всех записей и ждать, когда они все закончатся. Если не изменять сильно структуру кода, то вам нужно делать как-то так:

```
@dp.message_handler(commands=['check'])
async def cycle_restart(msg: types.Message):
    cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM table WHERE status = ?', ('correct',))
    rec = cursor.fetchall()
    jobs = {}
    for row in rec:
        code = row[3] #уникальный идентификатор
        uid = row[1] #ID пользователя
        job = aioschedule.every(5).seconds.do(count, c_id=code, u_id=uid)
        jobs[code] = job

    for code, job in jobs.items(): # повторяем для каждой запущенной задачи
        while True:     # этот цикл ждет когда завершится задача с кодом code
            await aioschedule.run_pending()
            cursor.execute('SELECT status FROM table WHERE id = ?', (code,))
            # т.к. code уникальный - запись всегда одна, можно делать fetchone
            status_row = cursor.fetchone()
            if status_row[0] == 'stop':
                aioschedule.cancel_job(job)
                continue  # выходим из цикла для текущей задачи
            await asyncio.sleep(1)
```

Еще одно замечание. Делать запрос `SELECT * FROM table WHERE status = ?`, а потом читать колонки по индексу - ненадежно, так как порядок полей, которые БД возвращает при использовании `*`, может измениться. Или явно указывайте имена полей `SELECT uid, code, и т.д FROM ...` или получайте поля по имени (как именно это делать, зависит от используемой БД).

Comment: Ох, спасибо вам огромное! Особенно за комментарии. Я действительно не учел момент, что цикл ждет достижения условия и потому не продолжается.